# Angular/PrimeNG open one modal dialog at index/value whenever clicking on that table value

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, primeng, ngfor, showdialog

```
**HTML CODE:**

<p-table [value]="SourcesEntities" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines">
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <h2>Entities</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <app-create-entity></app-create-entity>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
          <th>Entity Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Source</th>
          <th>Retrieval Frequency</th>
      </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entity let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr>
          <td>
            <button pButton
            label="{{entity.Ename}}"
            (click)="showDialog()"
            icon="pi pi-external-link"></button>
          </td>
          <td>{{entity.type}}</td>
          <td>{{entity.source}}</td>
          <td>{{entity.frequency}}</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- <p-dialog
      header="{{entity.Ename}} Attributes"
      [(visible)]="display"
      [breakpoints]="{'960px': '75vw', '640px': '100vw'}"
      [style]="{width: '50vw'}"></p-dialog> -->
  </ng-template>
</p-table>


***TS code:***

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {SourcesService} from '../sources.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sources-entities',
  templateUrl: './sources-entities.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sources-entities.component.css']
})
export class SourcesEntitiesComponent implements OnInit {

  SourcesEntities = [];
  SourcesAttributes =  [];
  display: boolean = false;
      

  showDialog(){
    //this function should get the index from which entity is clicked
    //then return a dialog with the content of that index + its attributes!
    //ngFor somehow breaks the table
    console.log('entity clicked')
    this.display = true;
  }
}

***Service.ts code:***

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { SourcesLogService } from './Sourceslog.service';

@Injectable()
export class SourcesService {

  private  SourcesEntities = [
    {Ename: 'Employees', type:'DB Table', source: 'sourceA', frequency: 'RF'},
    {Ename: 'Product', type: 'Web Service', source: 'sourceB', frequency: 'RF'},
    {Ename: 'Movies', type: 'Source file', source: 'sourceC', frequency: 'RF'}
  ];
  
  //These are the attributes that should be shown when you click on an entity Ename. One for
  //each row. i.e. George for Employees


  private SourcesAttributes = [
    {name: 'George', type: 'sofware dev'},
    {name: 'PC', type:'gaming'},
    {name: 'Star-Wars: The Phantom Menace', type: 'Sci-fy'}
  ]   
}
```

> [So in Summary I want when click on a value in Entity Name column to
> pop a dialog just for that one entity cell/row that will consists of that entity's attributes
> {Name,Description}.
> Instead I am getting
> multiple dialogs one for each row/entity name I have in my table. Hope
> that helps, Let me know if I should make my question more clear or if
> something doesnt make sense please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J7bY.png)
>
> I have tried using *ngFor="" but messes up with my table somehow...Probably I have used it
> on the wrong element or something. I am really new to angular so....

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMfb4.png
```

> You can see in the image my attributeData declared as

```
attributeData = [{
                   header: [],
                   data: [{name:''},{type:''}]
                }]
```

> If I dont declare it that way wont work. But still that way even if it works on my html attributeData.data.name data is not recognized. Sorry is just kind of confusing  for me:/

[image: > Blockquote]

Comment: Are you using the p-dialog markup inside the table?

Comment: I have tried adding it insiede the <td> under the button as well as right under the <tr> but both seem to act the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the showDialog() function by passing the header name & rowIndex to it.

   ```
   ** HTML Template **
   (click)="showDialog(entity.Ename, rowIndex)" 

   ** Component TS File **
   attributeData = {};
   showDialog(headerText, rowIndex) {
       this.attributeData['header'] = headerText;
       this.attributeData['data'] = this.SourcesAttributes[rowIndex];
       this.display = true;
   }
   ```
2. Place the p-dialog after the closing tag of p-table.

   ```
   </p-table>
   <p-dialog
    header="{{attributeData.header}} Attributes"
    [(visible)]="display"
    [breakpoints]="{'960px': '75vw', '640px': '100vw'}"
    [style]="{width: '50vw'}">
        Content Goes Here
        {{attributeData.data.name}}
        {{attributeData.data.type}}
   </p-dialog>
   ```

Comment: Thanks that worked...Been straggling by using ngFor etc.. all this time!

Comment: So I have a follow-up question on your answer. attributeData.data.name, Identifier data is not defined/recognized in this situation. I am unsure as to why :/ I even created a new array list like this    attributeData = [{
    header:[],
    data:[{name:''},{type:''}]
  }];
Although I made it work by using {{attributeData['data'].name}} which works...but feels wrong ;p

Comment: @Liquidus when the page component is mounting .name wont be existing and hence throwing the console error. You could simply do attributeData.data?.name to avoid it, meaning it property exist use it